# Macs on local network no longer appear in Network or Finder Sidebar for Screen Sharing

Tags: finder, network, sharing, screen-sharing, bonjour

I have a Mac Mini and MacBook connected within my local network. Both Macs have `System Preferences > Sharing > Screen Sharing` turned **On**.

For weeks I have seen each computer in the other's Finder sidebar. From there I was able to initiate Screen Sharing, browse the file system, etc.

Suddenly, today, they are no longer appearing. I have restarted both Macs multiple times.

[image: nothing in Network or Sidebar]

I can also not connect directly to them with the Screen Sharing app. Typing the computer's name in the `Connect To:` results in the error:

> Unable to resolve “MacName.local”
> Verify the name you entered and make sure your network connection is working.

`Finder > Go > Connect to Server...` similarly does not list any local Macs. Pressing `+` does strangely (re)add a shortcut to the Mac, which I've connected to before. But attempting to connect to it results in the error(s):

> There was a problem connecting to the server.
> URLs with the type “:” are not supported.
>
> There was a problem connecting to the server “MacName.local”.
> The server may not exist or it is unavailable at this time. Check the server name or IP address, check your network connection, and then try again.

**In modern macOS**, Big Sur or Monterey or newer, how can I reset this situation and see local network Macs in the Finder sidebar?

The solutions offered in a [similar previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148649/shared-devices-not-appearing-in-network) no longer seem to apply in modern macOS. Those plist files are no longer present on my machines. Is there a modern way to reset this network sharing?

Comment: Can you share screenshots of each computer's **System Preferences > Network** pane?

Comment: Have you install a  anti-virus or firewall software on your Mac? Verify in System Preferences/Security/Firewall the options.

Comment: The system firewall is **off** and no other anti-virus or firewall has been installed.

Comment: @pkamb Still waiting for those screenshots.

Comment: @pion they are both connected to the same Wi-Fi network. Is that what you want to see? That's basically the only info visible in that pane...?

Comment: @pkamb Can you show the **TCP/IP** pane in the **Advanced** sheet?

Comment: I added an answer to the linked question. My issue was caused by **Double NAT** from using 2 routers.

Answer (score -2):

This issue should be resolved by upgrading to MacOS 11.6.1, which is now publicly available.

Comment: Is this a known issue? Do you have a link to the issue and/or fix? Since asking this question I've upgraded both machines to macOS 12 Monterey (one was previously on Big Sur) and I'm still not seeing network Macs in the sidebar.