# "Share Disk" MacBook doesn't appear in "Network" section of the other Mac

Tags: finder, network, hard-drive, data-recovery

One of my laptops (MacBook pro with apple silicon) went kaput recently, and I'm trying to back up the files before I reinstall the OS. I can get it to enter disk sharing mode, but I can't get it to show up in the finder of the other mac (2019 MacBook Pro). The "Network" folder is just empty. I've tried checking finder settings to make sure network stuff is visible, but no dice. And the plist files discussed in [Shared devices not appearing in Network](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148649/shared-devices-not-appearing-in-network) don't seem to exist on my version of macOS.

I have the same problem when connecting to my partner's *really* old mac laptop (like 8 years old), but I was briefly able to connect via someone else's mac (don't know what version it was, didn't have time to go into depth or do a proper backup and now they're not around) and access files on my broken computer, so I think the issue exists with the other computers?

What I'm trying to do is [Transfer files between a Mac with Apple silicon and another Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-a-mac-apple-silicon-mchlb37e8ca7/mac).

Comment: It may depend on exactly what "went kaput". Did you try [Target Disk mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1443/mac)?

Comment: The nonworking macbook uses Apple Silicon. M2 chip, I think.

Comment: Also as far as what went kaput, I was running an update and when it powered back on it told me I needed to reinstall the OS from disk. And now it gets trapped in an endless restart loop when I log in to my user account

Comment: So, did you try target disk mode? btw theoretically, reinstalling the OS shouldn't touch the user data area at all - but the best time to do a backup is *before* you need it, not after. That's what Time Machine is for.

Comment: Target disk mode isn't for computers with Apple Silicon

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't realise they'd changed the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I updated the working macbook to the latest OS version (Ventura 13.1.1) and that seemed to do the trick. Not sure why though.